# launchd startInterval shorter than time taken for the script to complete

Tags: macos, launchd

I'm using launchctl to load/start my python script and it works to a certain degree. It launches ever 120s, but some times my script takes 500s to run and my theory is that is I have a process running it restarts it rather than letting the first one run.

What I think happens:
- launch tester.py (tester.py estimated time to complete 400s)
- after 120s
- launch tester.py again and abandon the first one

What I want:
To finish the first tester.py not restart it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>BuildNotification.py</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/usr/bin/python</string>
        <string>/Users/xcuer/tester.py</string>
    </array>
    <key>StartInterval</key>
    <integer>120</integer>
    <key>TimeOut</key>
    <integer>7200</integer>
    <key>ExitTimeOut</key>
    <integer>7200</integer>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: I’m trying to think of a good solution other than making the script check for previous invocations and exiting...

Comment: @bmike I'm trying to see if crontab resolves this issue

Comment: A lock file would be the traditional solution for this situation. Are you able to modify the script?

Comment: @GrahamMiln How would a lockfile work for my solution? Or is there a way I could write a bash script that launchctl calls instead of the python script itself? Does laucnhctl have a way to check if a service is currently running?

Comment: I have added an answer for the lock file approach.

Comment: I used the @GrahamMiln suggested answer for `crontab` and `launchd` jobs. His shell 4 lines test can be very easily written in Python, Perl, AppleScript or any scripting language.

Answer (score 1):

`launchd` focuses on launching jobs and keeping jobs running, it does not have a mechanism to handle overlapping jobs.

## Lock File

Traditionally in a UNIX environment, a lock file is used to stop processes from being run multiple times.

The core steps are:

1. On script launch, if the lock file already exists, stop the script.
2. On script launch, if the lock file does not exist, create the lock file.
3. On script finish, remove the lock file.

On macOS, create your lock file in `/var/tmp` for computer wide processes.

### Sample Implementation

```
if ! mkdir /var/tmp/myscript.lock 2>/dev/null; then
    echo "Myscript is already running." >&2
    exit 1
fi
```

See [Quick-and-dirty way to ensure only one instance of a shell script is running at a time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185451/) and [What is the best way to ensure only one instance of a Bash script is running?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1715137/) for sample scripts.

### Potential Problems

There are edge cases.

`launchd` wants jobs to run for at [least *n* seconds before finishing](https://lists.macosforge.org/pipermail/launchd-dev/2009-August/000601.html). When the script finds an existing lock file, consider sleeping for *n* seconds and then exiting.

What happens if your script is killed or exits because of an error? Can you be certain the lock file is removed?

In C, a trick to ensure a file's removal is to create, open, and delete the file – a deleted file held open on UNIX will remain until the opening process exits. The file is deleted even if the process crashes.

In a shell script, catch the terminate signal and ensure the file is removed.

Another potential problem is checking for the file existing. This check could happen factions of second before the previous script finishes. This will be rare but possible. The approach quoted above claims to overcome this.